# Using entry, StringVar and IntVar with Tkinter and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm new to python and when explaining things please make it beginner friendly :).
Basically when I try to run a reddit crawler using tkinter, I get all kinds of erros that I don't understand, Thanks in advance, I really appreciate the community.

Here is some of the essential code:

```
def Exas():
    import praw
    imgcount = 0
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CENSORED',
                         client_secret='CENSORED',
                         user_agent='TheBigScraper(By u/scrappermaster)',
                         username='scrappermaster',
                         password='thescrapperisscrap')

    listoftitles = []
    listofurls = []

    # whichone = input('what subreddit do you want to access? ')
    # endlimit = input('what number of pictures do you want to download? ')
    whichoner = whichone
    ender = int(endlimit.get())

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(whichone)
    for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=int(ender)):
        title = submission.title
        link = submission.url
        Both = title + " " + link
        if '.jpg' in link :
            listofurls.append(link)
            listoftitles.append(title)
```

And around 50 lines further down:

```
import tkinter as tk
import colorama

root = tk.Tk()


root.title("InstagramBot")

root.geometry('320x125')

whichone = str(tk.StringVar())
endlimit = tk.StringVar()

lblWhichone = tk.Label(root, text = 'Subreddit Name:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10)
entWhichone = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = whichone).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

lblIntendlimit = tk.Label(root, text = 'Number of Pictures:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10)
entendlimit = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = endlimit).grid(row = 1, column = 1)


btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Execute', command = Exas, fg='red', font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(row = 5, column = 1)
root.mainloop()

root.title("InstagramBot")
```

The Weird Error Code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/eucar/Documents/Testing/Compactor2000.py", line 28, in Exas
    for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=int(ender)):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 52, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 62, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 408, in get
    data = self.request('GET', path, params=params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 534, in request
    params=params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 185, in request
    params=params, url=url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 130, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.Redirect: Redirect to /subreddits/search
```

Comment: Try changing whichone=str(tk.StringVar()) to whichone=tk.StringVar().  Can you print the values of whichone.get() and endlimit.get() on the Exas function?

Comment: @TlsChris Yeah I tried that before and this time I get this error instead: https://textuploader.com/15txf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reduced Exas to a Tkinter based minimum.  I've never used the praw library and don't have it installed.

```
def Exas():
    whichoner = whichone.get()
    ender = int(endlimit.get())
    print(whichoner, ender)
```

Modifying your tkinter window for the StingVar I mentioned in the comment.

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("InstagramBot")

root.geometry('320x125+50+50')

whichone = tk.StringVar()
endlimit = tk.StringVar()

lblWhichone = tk.Label(root, text = 'Subreddit Name:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10)
entWhichone = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = whichone).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
# The grid method returns None!  All these variables have the value None.  
# I don't think it matters for what you're doing but may cause problems for you in the future. 
# In general this is better.
# entWhichone = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = whichone)
# entWhichone.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
# entWhichone now points to a tk.Entry object.

lblIntendlimit = tk.Label(root, text = 'Number of Pictures:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10)
entendlimit = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = endlimit).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Execute', command = Exas, fg='red', font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(row = 5, column = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

If I type test and 42 into your window it echos Test and 42 to my console.
Your latest error message indicates that a StringVar has been passed to a praw function or method.  In the Exas function you need:

```
whichoner = whichone.get() # Was it left at ... = whichone ?
```

If the above suggestions don't help, try printing whichoner and ender before anything else is called to check they return what you expect.

A style point is that in Python functions and variables are normally in lower case with underscore '_' to split, lbl_which_one instead of lblWhichone, exas for Exas.  Classes are named with a capital tk.Entry creates an object of class Entry.  Your code will still work just be bit more difficult for others to understand.

Comment: @TisChris Thanks, took some messing around but got it to work in the end :)